# Byte array to Bitmap not displayed Java Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, bitmap, arrays

i try to display a received byte[] as an Bitmap.

```
InputStream stream = mySocket.getInputStream();
byte[] datas = new byte[SIZE?];
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(datas, 0, datas.length);
ImageView view = new ImageView(MyServer.this);
view.setImageBitmap(bmp);
lChat.addView(view);
```

I don't know how big the byte Array should be and i don't know how to get the data of the inputStream in the byte[]. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There are many alternatives of parsing InputStream to byte[]. In my answer I've written one of them. Alos consider Google's suggestion while loading large bitmaps. If you don't, that may cause out of memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

Create `ByteArrayOutputStream` - it's an output stream in which the data is written into a byte array. Then use `copy()` method (taken from the [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)) to copy input stream to the output stream:

```
InputStream stream = mySocket.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
copy(stream, output);
byte[] data = output.toByteArray();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
...
```

Length of the `data` array will be the same as length of the data read from the input stream.

Please find `copy()` method below:

```
public static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    int n, count = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: (Then i have the length of it but what to do with it then? Create a new Array and do what i have written at the top?)
Edit: With the copy, all datas get in the Output and then in the 3rd line they are pushed in the Byte[] datas and then i can decode it with the BitmapFactory?

Comment: Edit2: the copy method is not available for me at Android

Comment: Definition of the `copy()` method is in answer, you have to paste it to your class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inputStreamToByteArray` method to parse `InputStream` to `byte[]`:

```
public byte[] inputStreamToByteArray(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    baos.flush();

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Also while loading large bitmaps consider Google's suggestion. Resize them for your needs. By doing this you'll prevent many memory failures:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(InputStream is, int requestedMaxWidth, int requestedMaxHeight) throws IOException {
    // parse inputStream to byte[]
    byte[] dataToBeDecode = inputStreamToByteArray(is);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    // First see the width and height of incoming bitmap            
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dataToBeDecode, 0, dataToBeDecode.length, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize for resizing
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, requestedMaxWidth, requestedMaxHeight);

    // Now resize and get the bitmap
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dataToBeDecode, 0, dataToBeDecode.length, options);

    return bitmap;
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2
        // and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

**Edit:** Read Google's loading large bitmaps doc. [See link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).